# Magento 2 Page Header Add Image, Change Color

Tags: magento-2.1, header, less-css

I am in my Magento_Theme Folder playing around with the _module.less file and have been trying to get it to change my background color of the header but I can't see any changes. I've cleared my cache.

I changed line 59 to:

```
.page-header {
        background-color: #07baba;
        border-bottom: 1px solid @border-color__base;
        margin-bottom: @indent__base;
```

and that did nothing. I also tried changing link 337 to add in the background color there and no results. I changed the border in 339 and nothing.

```
    .page-header {
        background-color: #07baba;
        border: 25;
        margin-bottom: 0;
```

Cleared cache etc. What am I missing?

Comment: Which type compilation you are used for css, Grunt or client side ?

Comment: [This page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_mode.html) of the Magento dev docs walks you through basic style changes. I strongly suggest reviewing that guide. Afterwards, work on [setting up Grunt](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html). It's really simple to do and will change your life.